# Connecting to a machine via remote desktop when blocked by firewall

Tags: remote-desktop, firewall

I am at a client site, and have a machine on Azure which I need to RDP onto.

The machine I have to work on is very locked down, as is the network, and as a result remote desktop just isn't connecting to my Azure machine. Ping is blocked also.

I have tried changing the RDP port of the Azure machine to 80, and specifying port 80 on my end when I try to connect, with no joy.

Does anybody know any tricks to get this to work? The Azure machine is 2008 R2, the machine I have to work on is XP (not a typo).

Thanks

Comment: My only suggestion is to ask some one to put teamviewer (or similar program) on the server so you can dial in via the browser.

Comment: Your chances are limited by the "locked-downess" of the network. If they filter traffic not only by packet headers but also by the content, there's little hope left unless there's a way to tunnel RDP over some other type of traffic that is allowed. That being said, have you verified the RDP on the Azure machine really works on port 80 from some other location?

Comment: One way to check if the network is letting you out at all is to use some tool which provides TCP traceroute. For example, [download nmap Windows command line version](http://nmap.org/download.html) (so you don't need to install anything on the client XP box), unzip it and try `nmap.exe -Pn --traceroute -p 80 <azure_ip_address>`. (please note that if the network is restricted due to security policy, trying to pass through the restrictions might be seen as a violation)